# Align Text of second col at bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-tables

I have a Table with two Cols. In the first Col there is text (sometimes more than one line). on the right(second Col) there is a price. The height of the Col is the Lineheight from the Price I think. Thats why it has no effect to have: vertical-align:bottom;.

So the `<TD>` right have to get the same height then the  on the left. How can I do this?

My css:

```
.col-1{
    width:363px !important;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    float:left !important;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 27px !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align:bottom !important;
}
.col-2{
    float:right !important;
    background-color:#FFF !important;
    width:100px !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    text-align:right;
    height:100% !important;
    vertical-align:bottom !important;
}
```

Comment: please post yuor HTML code also. Or share fiddle demo.

Comment: here is a link: http://test.max-cafe-bar.de/?cat=3 i have to do some formating also. but this is not the problem.

Comment: where you want to align text at bottom exactly?

Comment: the prices are on top. i want to have them at the bottom. so the producttext is on the left and the price(only one line) on the right.

Comment: You are using a WordPress theme, with a fairly complex style sheet.  You should say this in the question, it makes all the difference in how the question should be answered.

Comment: ah. ok. sorry. i ll do this in the future.

Comment: Also...you are obviously **massively** overusing `!important`. There should be no reason to do so with properly structured CSS.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you look , you should use or `inline-block` or `table` `display`.

`Inline-block` example

```css
.col-1{
    width:363px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 27px;
    margin:0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.col-2{

    background-color:#FFF ;
    width:100px;
    padding:0 ;
    margin:0;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:bottom ;
}
div {
  border:solid;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-1">
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus .</p>
</div><div class="col-2"v>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
```

or `display:table;` & `display:table-cell;`

```css
.col-1{
        width:363px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 27px;
        margin:0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
    .col-2{

        background-color:#FFF ;
        width:100px;
        padding:0 ;
        margin:0;
        text-align:right;
        vertical-align:bottom ;
    }
    div {
      border:solid;
      display: table;
    }
div>div {
  display:table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="col-1"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`Float` will not mind your vertical-align rule.

Comment: Thnk you. i will try this out.